# Generated column without taking up space

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns, create-table

I have in post a column I need to generate, which follows a naming pattern. 
The pattern is unique for each table, but will always include some sort of suffix or prefix, and the current row value of the some of it columns.

```
-- Create table_registration
ALTER TABLE public.person
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS entry_name, 
ADD COLUMN entry_name TEXT generated ALWAYS as (concat_ws(' ', hobby)) stored;
```

This sometimes trigger an error like

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: '42P17: generation expression is not immutable'
```

I then became aware of this might not be what I would like to to do, since it basically the same as a new column and takes up space -  from basically do logic operation.

Is there someway I can generate this -  and modify this without taking of space, and if that is not possible why I am not able to drop the columns once it has been added?

Answer (score 0):

As of Postgres 12, generated columns are always `stored`. Support for `virtual` generated columns, whose values are computed on the fly (and hence occupy no storage) might be implemeted in future versions.

A straight-forward alternative is to use a `view` instead:

```
create view person_view as
select p.*, concat_ws(' ', hobby) entry_name
from public.person p
```

Comment: I would still need to drop the view in case of the pattern changed.. and when I do that I get the same issue with `generation expression is not immutable` - some how I can overcome this?